# Best way to get balances of multitude of addresses

Tags: addresses, synchronization, balances

I have a list/array/map of addresses.

I want to keep track of their balances on the front end.
Currently, the front end is calling the `balanceOf()` function for each address and updating based on the response.

However, this is getting time-consuming. So I need a way of getting data faster instead of calling Blockchain separately for each address.

I would appreciate any advice on how to deal with this.

Comment: See [The Graph](https://thegraph.com) and [Multicall](https://github.com/joshstevens19/ethereum-multicall).

Comment: Not sure about The Graph, but the Multicall seems like the right choice in my situation. Will go over it.